# How to prevent content deletion in container when using Docker Compose and bind mount?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the Dockerfile and the compose file below. In the dockerfile, I create a new symfony application if there is no application yet. The process is working well when I run `docker compose build --build-arg CREATE_APP=true --no-cache --pull`.
But when I run `docker compose up -d` then as my ./app/ folder is empty on the host, the content of `/var/www/html` is deleted in the container.

How can I prevent this from happening? Maybe the entire method is incorrect. Should I create the app after once the containers are running?

```docker
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
FROM php:8.2.3-fpm-alpine
ARG TIMEZONE
ARG SYMFONY_VERSION=6.*
ARG CREATE_APP=false
ARG GIT_USER_NAME
ARG GIT_USER_EMAIL

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        acl \
        fcgi \
        file \
        gettext \
        git \
        unzip \
    ;

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions gd xdebug intl pdo_mysql zip opcache apcu @composer

# Set timezone
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && echo ${TIMEZONE} > /etc/timezone \
    && printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "%s"\n', ${TIMEZONE} > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini \
    && "date"

COPY --link xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
COPY --link ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-config.ini

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash \
    &&  mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin

# Install symfony if required
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN set -eux; \
    if [ "${CREATE_APP}" = "true" ]; then \
        # composer create-project symfony/skeleton:${SYMFONY_VERSION} . --stability=stable; \
        # composer require webapp; \
        git config --global --add safe.directory /var/www/html; \
        git config --global user.name ${GIT_USER_NAME} ; \
        git config --global user.email ${GIT_USER_EMAIL}; \
        symfony new . --webapp; \
    fi


WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

```docker
version: '3'
services:
    php:
        build:
            context: ./docker/php
            args:
                TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
                username: ${username}
                GIT_USER_NAME: ${GIT_USER_NAME}
                GIT_USER_EMAIL: ${GIT_USER_EMAIL}
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - backend
        volumes:
            - ./app/:/var/www/html
```

Comment: in the compose file, the local directory `./app` is mounted to `/var/www/html`, Thus, the previous content of `/var/www/html` is "shadowed" (it is still there, but not accessible). If we want to use the content that is already present in `/var/www/html`, we should remove the mount.

Comment: Ok understood. But how can I get the mount and the previous content? I need to work on my code in the host machine and have the code in the container to run the app.